# приложение перестало работать

Tags: android, android-studio, android-sdk, отладка

пишу приложение на андройд. Пользуюсь телефоном как эмулятором чтоб проверять приложение на ошибки. В один прекрасный день телефон перестал логиниться в приложении, то есть открывает первую страницу приложения а дальше не в какую хотя логин и пароль ввожу правильно. Скидываю апк на другие телефоны все работает а на моем нет, подскажите пожалуйста что можно с этим поделать не могу найти в интернете ничего похожего

Answer (score 1):

Попробуй очистить кэш приложения, или перепрошей свой телефон.
Раз на других устройствах работает значит эта ошибка индивудуальная.

Comment: вот именно что тестил на 2 абсолютно разных девайсах и сейчас на обоих не работает может быть когда производишь debug в телефоне что то сохраняется? Если да то подскажите где?

Comment: @Sergey, вы пробовали данные приложения чистить? Как вы логинитесь? Скорее всего что-то в sharedPreferenes записывается и потом ломается. А может вы из соц.провайдеров не разлогинились. Мало подробностей. Очистка данных должна решить временно проблему.

Comment: кеш чистил в телефоне, билд скидывал в android studio, что еще в телефоне можно почистить, а если проблема с sharedPreferences что можно сделать чтоб от нее избавится @ЮрийСПб

Comment: через эмулятор от android studio все работает, то есть вряд ли проблема в коде

Comment: Очистка кэша, данных,  удаление и переустановка приложения это 4 разных сосем действия. Вы таки данные очищали? И Раскройте детали реализации-без них можно только такие общие ответы давать.

Comment: @ЮрийСПб приложение удалял, переустанавливал и с апк и с debug правда, когда с апк ставишь оно не проходит этап debug и там стоит либо отменить, либо ждать, но он не продебажит. Кеш очищал, а вот об очистке данных сомневаюсь что за данные нужно очистить?

Comment: В списке всех приложений если выбрать приложение будет две кнопки-очистить данные и очистить кэш. Я про первую говорю.

Comment: @ЮрийСПб а сама android studio ничего не создает в телефоне при дебаге может у меня там что то крашнулось?

Comment: @Sergey, про дебггер не знаю - за годы практики ни разу не использовал, но не должен.

Comment: @Sergey, раз вы не хотите показать код, то последнее что можно предложить - отключить `InstantRun` в настройках студии.

Comment: @ЮрийСПБ что конкретно нужно потому что код слишком большой чтоб постить его полностью

Comment: Ну... Я не знаю. Наверное код перехода на следующую активити?..

Comment: @ЮрийСПб       protected void onPostExecute(String result) {
        if (result == null ) {
            Toast pass = Toast.makeText(context, "Email or Password is not match!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT);
            pass.show();
        }
        else
        {
            context.startActivity( new Intent(context,Main.class));
            Main.JSON_STRING = result;
            Main.name = name;
            Main.win_user = win_user;
            Main.cookie = cookies;
            Toast pass = Toast.makeText(context, cookies, Toast.LENGTH_LONG);
            pass.show();
        }
    }